# Fix variances to specific values in lme4/lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I am doing a simulation study for a mixed effect model (three levels; observations nested within subjects within schools):

```
f <- lmer(measurement ~ time + race + gender + s_ses + 
   fidelity + (1 + time|school/subject), mydata_long, REML=0)
```

The model allows the intercept and time slope to vary across subjects and schools. I am wondering how I can fix the variances to be specific values. I do know how to do that when there is only random intercept:

```
VarCorr(f)['subject:school']<-0.13
VarCorr(f)['school']<-0.20
```

However, when there is a random slope, these codes don't work since there are different components in the variance aspect (see the attached picture).

[image: variance components]

How can I fix the variances of subject: school (Intercept), subject:school time, school (Intercept), and school time to specific values in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: how are you performing the simulation?  `?simulate.merMod` should help. The key is that the variance-covariance parameters (theta) for each component are specified by the Cholesky factor for the variance-covariance matrix.  (Sorry if that's not clear; hopefully I can find some more links tomorrow ...)

Comment: It's not clear to me what `VarCorr(f)['subject:school']<-0.13` is supposed to do, or it how it works (I get `could not find function "VarCorr<-"`)

Answer (score 1):

A simulation example. The hardest part is getting the random-effects parameters correctly specified: the key things you need to know are (1) internally the random effects variance matrix is scaled by the residual variance; (2) for vector-valued random effects (like this random-slopes model), the variance-covariance matrix is specified in terms of its *Cholesky factor*: if we want covariance matrix `V`, there is a lower-triangular matrix such that `C %*% t(C) == V`. We compute `C` using `chol()`, then read off the elements of the lower triangle (including the diagonal) in column-major order (see helper functions below).

Set up experimental design (simplified from yours, but with the same random effects components):

```
mydata_long <- expand.grid(time=1:40,
                           school=factor(letters[1:25]),
                           subject=factor(LETTERS[1:25]))
```

Helper functions to convert **from**

- a vector of standard deviations, one or more correlation parameters (in lower-triangular/column major order), and a residual standard deviation

**to**

- a vector of "theta" parameters as used internally by `lme4` (see description above)

... and back the other way (`conv_chol`)

```
conv_sc <- function(sdvec,cor,sigma) {
    ## construct symmetric matrix with cor in lower/upper triangles
    cormat <- matrix(1,nrow=length(sdvec),ncol=length(sdvec))
    cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- cor
    cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- t(cormat)[upper.tri(cormat)]
    ## convert to covariance matrix and scale by 1/sigma^2
    V <- outer(sdvec, sdvec)*cormat/sigma^2
    ## extract lower triangle in column-major order
    return(t(chol(V))[lower.tri(V,diag=TRUE)])
}
conv_chol <- function(ch, s) {
    m <- matrix(NA,2,2)
    m[lower.tri(m,diag=TRUE)] <- ch
    m[upper.tri(m)] <- 0
    V <- m %*% t(m) * s^2
    list(sd=sqrt(diag(V)), cor=cov2cor(V)[1,2])
}
```

If you want to start from covariance matrices rather than standard deviations and correlations you can modify the code to skip some steps (starting and ending with `V`).

Pick some values and convert (and back-convert, to check)

```
tt1 <- conv_sc(c(0.7, 1.2), 0.3, 0.5)
tt2 <- conv_sc(c(1.4, 0.2), -0.2, 0.5)
tt <- c(tt1, tt2)


conv_chol(tt1, s=0.5)
conv_chol(tt2, s=0.5)
```

Set up formula and simulate:

```
form <- m ~ time + (1 + time|school/subject)
set.seed(101)
mydata_long$m <- simulate(form[-2],  ## [-2] drops the response
                          family=gaussian,
                          newdata=mydata_long,
                          newparams=list(theta=tt,
                                         beta=c(1,1),
                                         sigma=0.5))[[1]]
                              
f <- lmer(form, data=mydata_long, REML=FALSE)
VarCorr(f)
```

The fitted results are close to what we requested above ...

```
 Groups         Name        Std.Dev. Corr  
 subject:school (Intercept) 0.66427        
                time        1.16488  0.231 
 school         (Intercept) 1.78312        
                time        0.22459  -0.156
 Residual                   0.49772
```

Now do the same thing 200 times, to explore the distribution of estimates:

```
simfun <- function() {
    mydata_long$m <- simulate(form[-2],
                              family=gaussian,
                              newdata=mydata_long,
                              newparams=list(theta=tt,
                                             beta=c(1,1),
                                             sigma=0.5))[[1]]
                              
    f <- lmer(form, data=mydata_long, REML=FALSE)
    return(as.data.frame(VarCorr(f))[,"sdcor"])
}

set.seed(101)
res <- plyr::raply(200,suppressMessages(simfun()),.progress="text")
```

Here `plyr::raply()` is used for convenience, you can do this however you like (`for` loop, `lapply()`, `replicate()`, `purrr::map()` ...)

```
par(las=1)
boxplot(res)
## add true values to the plot
points(1:7,c(0.7,1.2,0.3,1.4,0.2,-0.3,0.5),col=2,cex=3,lwd=3)
```

[image]